# How to make one CiviCRM work with Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

My organisation is using CiviCRM on Wordpress. We recently changed the Wordpress installation to be a multi-site network. CiviCRM, the plugin, is now only activiated for the subsite that was the original one. If we were to create new sites that shall also interact with the same CiviCRM database, would we just have to activate the plugin network-wide, or is [this](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/#wordpress-multisites) precisely what we have to do?

In the end, we want to have forms on each of the different sites and have people enter their details and sign for things, which are then stored in the (same) CiviCRM database.

I know this is a dumb question, but I am just not sure about any of these things and don't want to break anything.

Comment: I'd set up a test instance and try different combinations out. The CiviCRM Admin Utilities plugin has options that may help in this regard. https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/

Answer (score 1):

For the multisite integration across websites to work, yes you do need to do what is [outlined here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/#wordpress-multisites). That with some a few enhancement that https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/, which Christian noted above, allows you to connect multiple websites on a WordPress multisite to the same CiviCRM instance.

Answer (score 0):

H Simon,

thanks for sharing your question! If I understand your problem correctly the Form Processor extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor) might help you to let different Wordpress sites communicate with the only CiviCRM installation?